# Word meaning “someone who is good with large numbers”

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or an expression to denote such a person?

Comment: @tchrist I'm not sure whether that is such a good duplicate, can you please explain why you think it is a good duplicate?

Comment: Depending on how large the numbers are you mean, [*googologist*](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Googology) could be an answer.